# heroku login/installation problems (ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: heroku, ubuntu-12.04

I have tried to install heroku on my system (64bit ubuntu 12.04) and it throws no errors when actually installing.  However, when I try heroku login, I get this error:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux/readline.so: libreadline.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux/readline.so (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.31.4/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:1
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.31.4/lib/heroku/command.rb:14:in `load'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.31.4/lib/heroku/command.rb:13:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.31.4/lib/heroku/command.rb:13:in `load'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.31.4/lib/heroku/cli.rb:27:in `start'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.31.4/bin/heroku:16
    from /usr/local/bin/heroku:19:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/heroku:19
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have these installed:

`$ sudo apt-get install curl bison build-essential autoconf zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libxml2-dev libreadline6-dev git-core`

Comment: That does not help. I installed all the libraries above and then also reinstalled heroku using their script, I am still getting the same error as the OP